# An interpolation inequality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, integration, interpolation

I am interested in the following statement. Let $q>p$. Then there are positive numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that for all $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, one has
$$ \left(\int|\nabla f|^p dx\right)^\frac{1}{p} \leq C \left(\int|f|^p dx\right)^\frac{\alpha}{p} \left(\int|\nabla f|^q dx\right)^\frac{\beta}{q}. $$
Does someone have an idea or a reference?

Comment: Thank you, I learned that it was a special case of Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality. Will the proof simplify in my case?

Comment: The problem is that you're in the whole space, right? So my strategy would be trying to control the decay of $|\nabla f|$ by $\|f\|_{L^p}$, up to trading-off with a small fraction of the higher $\|\nabla f\|_q$, Have you tried for radial functions $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|^\delta}$ to identify possible candidates for $\alpha,\beta$?

Comment: I deleted my answer, as it is NOT a special case of Gagliardo-Nirenberg (since you want identical orders of derivatives in both sides of the inequality, $j=m=1$ and therefore $\alpha=1$ in Wikipedia's notations, hence Gagliardo-Nirenberg is completely vacuous in this setting)

Comment: Thank you. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ will have to solve $\alpha+\beta=1$ and $-1+\frac{n}{p} = \alpha\frac{n}{p} + \beta(-1 + \frac{n}{q})$ because of scaling invariance. I cannot read what you mean with $\delta$?

Comment: well, since the problem is decay at infinity, the natural "test-case" for your inequality is my $\frac{1}{|x|^\delta}$ functions (away from zero, of course). So I suggest you test your inequality with your specific values $\alpha,\beta=[\dots]$ and see if it holds for this whole family of functions. If it does it's a good sign. If it doesn't then it's the end of the road.

Comment: Radial functions do not seem to provide a counterexample...

Comment: Just for clarification, $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $C$ are independent of $f$? And, why the term interpolation inequality?

Comment: I want to indicate that one of the norms on the right hand side is weaker than the one on the left hand side while the other is stronger. We have that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ depend on $p$, $q$ as explained above. Also $C$ is meant independent of $f$.

Answer (score 3):

Such an inequality is false. Take $n=1$, $\phi$ a standard cut-off function supported in $[0,1]$ and $f=\sum_n c_n \phi (\frac{x-n}{r_n})$. Then $\|f\|_p \approx \sum_n |c_n|^p r_n$, $\|f'\|_p \approx \sum_n \frac{|c_n|^p}{r_n^{p-1}}$, $\|f'\|_q \approx \sum_n \frac{|c_n|^p}{r_n^{q-1}}$. If $p=1$, $q=2$, $c_n=1/n$ and $r_n=(\log n)^{-2}$ then $f\in L^1$, $f' \in L^2$, $f' \not \in L^1$.

Comment: True. Thank you.